# JS - When `window.location.hostname` is being changed or being compared to another variable. Have it look like a different value

Tags: javascript

for context what I am trying is for `window.location.hostname` to keep its value but when its being compared like this `if (window.location.hostname != example.org)` the if statement sees it as `example.org`. This is for a web proxy injection script to have the `window.location` objects appear as the `window.location` objects for the website thats being proxied. This is possible since on my friends web proxy it does this exact thing I am talking about. I don't have code to give sicne I don't know how to do this but I would love for someone to help me out solve this.

Comment: The location object itself is immutable and cannot be overwritten. But, the various location object properties can be changed. This, in turn, changes the location object.

Comment: In your `if` statement, you should be wrapping `example.org` in quotes, like `if (window.location.hostname != "example.org")`

Comment: Oh I understand that I need to wrap `example.org` in quotes. I forgot to add it